# Specifying pointers as restrict only in declaration?

Tags: c, c99, restrict

So my question is this. If in a header file I have a function declaration:

```
extern void func(void* restrict, void* restrict);
```

and then in a source file, I define it as such:

```
void func(void*, void*) {}
```

is this a problem? Are the `restrict` qualifiers lost?

***P.S.*** This is so I can compile the source file in C89 mode and change the prototype in the header to the respective C89/C99 version with a conditional macro.

Comment: if you have a conditional macro, why are you even trying to make one definition cover both cases? The "correct" way to deal with such scenarios is to either supply two declarations, split by the macro guard, or hide the problematic keyword under a macro identifier, itself given different definitions by the guard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"This is so I can compile the source file in C89 mode" - Simple reason: `restrict` is not a reserved keyword until C99 [see forword of C11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Forewordp7) (C99 is the 2nd edition), so it will just be used as a name, which is ignored in the prototype.

But both function declarators (prototype and definition) have to specify the same type, i.e. `restrict` is required in both.

You have to compile the header and the implemenation with the correct C version. For `restrict` the definition is typically more relevant than the prototype, but the compiler might be able to detect violations in the caller. Always assume relying on such hacks breaks your code.

---

After a the comments, trying a bit of clairvoyancy:

If you want to make the code compile with ancient C90, yet take advantage of newer features where useful, you can use a macro:

```
#if this_is_c99_or_c11
#define RESTRICT retrict
#else
#define RESTRICT
#endif

void f(int * RESTRICT p);

...

void f(int * RESTRICT p)
{
    ...
}
```

Still remember there can be problems cross-version compiling caller and callee. Check your target's ABI.

Comment: It will be used as a name, which is ignored, but it will also fail to compile because of 'redefinition of parameter'

Comment: Where do you mean it will fail? Please read the last sentence of my first paragraph. `void *` is not allowed in the declarator of the definition.

Comment: Declaring a function as `void f(void* restrict, void* restrict);` fails to compile in my `clang-3.9` in C89 mode and I quote `error: redefinition of parameter 'restrict'`. Otherwise your answer told me what I was already doing in practice, so I will mark as correct.

Comment: Wait - do you want to use `restrict` as paramter name?

Comment: No! There seems to be some miscommunication problem. XD I fear I may have misunderstood your first paragraph or maybe not. I was only wondering if it's okay to do what I described in the question. Apparently not.

Comment: @DeiDei: read my answer again. Maybe that's what you want. But be aware using modern C from older versions. There are subtle differences (mostly due to being unspecified in C90).